# Every compact, connected, orientable surface without boundary admits a $\Delta$ complex structure

Tags: algebraic-topology

Every compact, connected, orientable surface without boundary admits a $\Delta$ complex structure

I'm not sure if the approach I'm using is even correct.

But basically, I know that every compact surface is triangulable. The triangulation of such a surface $S$ results in a simplicial complex $|K|$. Let $\alpha$ be a set of simplices. Then we can construct $\sigma_\alpha:\Delta^n\rightarrow|K|$ for each simplex $\alpha$ of $K$, where $n$ is the dimension of $K$. Hence $S$ admits a $\Delta$ complex structure.

Comment: Yes that seems right. You should just show every simplicial complex is a delta complex.

Comment: Is that not just a trivial observation?

Comment: @Tim - that isn't true.  There is an example with one triangle, one edge, and one vertex.

Comment: Which counterexample is this for?

Comment: Oops!  I was confused.  Tim is correct - every simplicial complex can be given the structure of a $\Delta$-complex.  I was referring to an example of a CW--complex where all the cells are simplices, all the attaching maps are linear, but the structure is not a $\Delta$-complex.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Also, Tim's hint is on-point.  It suffices to show (a) every surface admits a simplicial complex structure and (b) every simplicial complex can be given the structure of a $\Delta$-complex.